# Android Camera preview on two views ( Multi-lenses camera preview )

Tags: android, android-camera

I need two camera previews in my app. However, android camera can give only one preview at a time. Is there any way to pipeline/copy that preview to another view? I came across this question [How to create multi lenses or preview using one camera in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019036/how-to-create-multi-lenses-or-preview-using-one-camera-in-android) and he says that

`On Android 3.0 or later, you can use the setPreviewTexture method to pipe the preview data into an OpenGL texture, which you can then render to multiple quads in a GLSurfaceView or equivalent.`

But I have no idea how to render that to multiple quads in `GLSurfaceView`.I need to support android 4.0+. But I don't want to use preview frame from preview callback. It causes significant delay. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Here is my code for single preview

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceTextureListener{

    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView1;
    private TextureView mTextureView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextureView1 = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
        mTextureView2 = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView2);

        mTextureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
            int height) {


        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(getCameraId());
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
            CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(getCameraId(), cameraInfo);
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, getCameraId(), mCamera);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
            int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }


}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to have preview frames from a *single* camera shown in two adjacent windows, or preview frames from *two different cameras* shown side-by-side?

Comment: @fadden I need preview from single camera shown in two adjacent Windows.

Comment: @fadden But as I said, I don't want to use `onPreviewFrame` to get the individual frames as it introduces some delay.

Comment: @AbhishekV  have u achieved this task can u pls share how u have done i also stuck at the same point  can u help me

Comment: @ ErumHannan I couldn't solve that problem. It was only small module in our project and I couldn't spend much time on that as I got busy on other projects. I ended up using preview frames from **onPreviewFrame()** method. It is not that bad either and if you can set the camera preview size properly according to your needs, there is absolutely no delay at all.

Comment: Please share your working code.I am new to all stuff and facing same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by sending the camera preview to a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) instead of a Surface associated with a View.  That takes the output of the camera and makes it available for use as a GLES texture.

Then, instead of having two `TextureViews`, just render two textured quads with GLES, each of which occupies half of a single View.  This is easier than rendering to two different surfaces (only one EGL context to worry about).  If you haven't worked with OpenGL ES before there can be a bit of a learning curve.

The pieces you need can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  Consider for example the "Continuous capture" and "Show + capture camera" activities.  Both direct the camera output to a `SurfaceTexture` and render it twice.  For these, it's once to the screen and once to the input of a video encoder, but it's the same idea.  If you look at "Hardware scaler exerciser" you can see it blitting a textured quad that bounces around the screen; you can use this as an example of how to set the size and position of the quad.

There's also "Double decode", which is using a pair of `TextureViews` to show two decoded movies side-by-side.  You don't want to do what it does -- it's receiving content from two different sources, not showing a single source twice.

The various activities use GLES with `TextureView`, `SurfaceView`, and `GLSurfaceView`.  Each view type comes with unique benefits and limitations.

**Update:** The new(er than this answer) "[texture from camera](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java)" activity is probably the closest to what you want.  It sends the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture and demonstrates how to move, resize, rotate, and zoom the image by rendering it with GLES.

Comment: Thank You. I will work on the examples you provided and let you know.

Comment: @AbhishekV  can u pls tell me will this solution works for u ? can u pls help me may i need to send cameraInstance.startPreview() to SurfaceTexture ??

Comment: @user3233280 I didn't work on that problem further.Have a look at Grafika project. I am sure you will find some useful code there.

Comment: Updated the answer -- I added a "texture from camera" activity a couple months later that renders the camera preview with GLES.