# How to show camera in 2 views for android

Tags: android, mobile

I am a new for android.
Now I make a prototype for showing camera in 2 views.
I already checked this URL([Android Camera preview on two views ( Multi-lenses camera preview )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529981/android-camera-preview-on-two-views-multi-lenses-camera-preview)), but I can't do that now.

Please give me a full course.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to draw the camera into an OpenGL texture and show the texture.

Mikle wrote two versions of this here, feel free to modify the code and add pull requests:
https://github.com/Sveder/CardboardPassthrough

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I can see the white rectangle, not camera. I used the OpenGL version. Please let me know the reason why.